# ¿Cómo mostrar la primera pagina de múltiples pdf en un html?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

He visto el ejemplo que tienen en la pagina de PDF.js:

https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/

Lo hace con promesas de javascript, pero solo con un pdf. No he conseguido replicar esto.

¿Cómo se hace?

Comment: Utiliza `Promise.all(...)`

Comment: fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/tzkrtqx4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que veo en su docu. la cosa es bastante sencilla.

```
// Cargas tu fichero .pdf
PDFJS.getDocument('nombre-de-tu-archivo.pdf').then(function(pdf) {
  // Cuando el archivo se ha cargado pides la primera pag.
  pdf.getPage(1).then(function(page) {
    // Cuando la página se ha cargado la pintas
  });
});
```

Para 'pintar' la primera página tienes un ejemplo de como hacerlo en la docu. que has pasado, entiendo que igual que pintas una puedes pintar varias.
Si tienes problemas pegamos tú código o crea un [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) e intentaremos ayudarte.